# Webkit keyframes not working on safari or chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, css-animations

I have been trying to find a solution on how i can get my safari browser to apply the animation using CSS3. I have already declared webkit on my css to make work on chrome or safari. In mozilla it animates perfectly but in safari/chrome it only makes the texts appear

Here is the fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/azSCP/1/) and below is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="animation">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>n</div>
    <div>i</div>
    <div>m</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>t</div>
    <div>e</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animation div{
    float:left; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:80px;
    display:inline; 
    margin-right:5px;
    visibility:hidden
}

.animate_letters{
    -moz-animation:fancytext 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 2, 0.35, 1.45) 0s normal none 1;
    -webkit-animation:fancytext 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 2, 0.35, 1.45) 0s normal none 1;
    animation:fancytext 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 2, 0.35, 1.45) 0s normal none 1;
    visibility:visible !important
}

@keyframes fancytext{
  from {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:1;
  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes fancytext{
  from {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:1;
  }

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.animation div').each(function(ii){
        var data = $(this);
        setTimeout( function () {
            $(data).addClass('animate_letters')
        }, ii * 100);
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azSCP/3/)**

change `scale(0) translateX(-40%)` to `scale(1) translateX(0%)` ,  in `to{}`

```
@keyframes fancytext{
  from {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    `------------------------^`           `^---------------`
  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes fancytext{
  from {
    transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateX(-40%); opacity:0;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateX(0%); opacity:1;
    `------------------------^`           `^---------------` 
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks, i have corrected the errors that i have overlooked it now works on google chrome but still not working on safari